# Call recording app for android

Tags: android, audio-recording, phone, voice-recording

I am looking for a software which records my calls on Android. Recording means the conversation and not the logs, so I need the calls recorded.

**Features I require** :

- Record outgoing/incoming calls of me and the person with whom I am talking with
- Unlimited Recording
- No Beeps or other sound between the calls
- Cloud Sync
- Consumes less memory / audio file

Comment: BTW Do you know that in some countries you are legally required to tell the person you're talking with that the call is being recorded? You may want to check that out for your country.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The app that would suit your requirements is [Automatic Call Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appstar.callrecorder) / [Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appstar.callrecorderpro).

**Features :**

- Record any phone call you want, and choose the ones you want to auto save everytime.
- Set which contacts should be recorded and which shouldn't
- Listen the recordings, save notes, share the audio file.
- Integration with Google Drive and Dropbox for storing the recordings on cloud.
- Change the destination of recording folder to external card.
- Set the limit of recordings in your inbox.

> Note: If the record limit exceeds the maximum number of inbox limit,
>   the older records will be deleted automatically from your phone.
>
> Also note that some of the features listed above are available in Pro
>   version only (which costs 5.30€ or $6.99), such as Cloud Integration.

---

Screenshots for the above software :

[image] [image] [image]

<sup>Credits for Screenshot : Automatic Call Recorder *(Google PlayStore)*</sup>

Comment: Are you affiliated with the developers?

Comment: Are your "Note …" and "Also note …" really quotes?

Comment: @DeerHunter Why do you think so? Is that really bad to contribute question/answer by self? If it's so I will stop doing that

Comment: It's not bad at all. If there's any conflict of interest, though, the users have to know.

Comment: @DeerHunter If you need the answer of your question than the answer is NO :) anyways I've raised a question on Meta regarding this, as this particular functionality of "Answer my own question" conflicts with the websites concept.

Comment: This is a great app, no unnecessary permission requests, no ads in the pro version. Even the free version has only 2 ad sources (Google & DoubleClick), so it's quite light on traffic.

Answer (score 2):

If you've **root access** .

(***Works For Any Samsung Device with android 4.4.x and above***)

you can enable record option in Calling UI just by editing some values in `/system/csc/feature.xml`

just go through this [**thread in xda**](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s5/development/mod-enable-call-recording-s5-stock-rom-t2873434) for more details

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try [Call Recorder (IntCall)](http://www.telestarint.net/call-recorder) app. You can use it to record from any Android-enabled device, it also works for iPhone, iPad, and iPod. It works for both outgoing and incoming calls.