# Free phone recording application for Android

Tags: gratis, android, phone, audio-recording

I was talking to a good friend of mine on my Android phone, which suddenly made me think of finding an application to install on my Android.

Could you recommend me some please?

Comment: out of curiosity, what does talking to a friend have to do with sound recording?

Comment: @Hack-R I see. :)

Comment: Similar: [Call recording app for android](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/3348/3474).

Answer (score 1):

I use [Smart Voice Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andrwq.recorder).

I like the app. It has ads but works fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

The app I use is called **Automatic Call Recorder** ([Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appstar.callrecorder) / [Aptoide](https://m.aptoide.com/app/40519195)). It's free (with ads, but only from Google, no Facebook tracking and such), requires no fancy permissions and worked with all phones I've had so far. There's a paid version if you want to get rid of ads or want to save recordings to Dropbox / Google Drive.

I used to use [Androrec](https://m.aptoide.com/app/20558634) which is gratis *and* ad-free, plus it's very lightweight (800kB). Unfortunately, it didn't work with my latest phone, but it's still worth a try.