# Call recording app for iPhone

Tags: iphone-app, audio-recording

Similar to [Android](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/3348/3474), I am looking for call recording app for iPhone.

#### Features

- It needs to support recording of incoming and outgoing calls.
- Option to have no beeps between intervals.
- Easy transfer or sharing the recordings.
- Support for MP3 format.
- Support for long calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [Call Recorder (IntCall)](http://www.telestarint.net/call-recorder) app and it seems to work great. It works for iOS and Android-enabled device.

It can record both outgoing and incoming calls. Since Apple got some restrictions for that kind of apps, the recording is archived via merging the calls. It is not free, but worth to try.

I have successfully used it to record the scammers. The calls can be downloaded as MP3 or shared by a link.