# Call recording on Android 11

Tags: android, audio-recording, phone, voice-recording

I have been happily using Total Recall on Android 7 for several years to automatically record all my phone calls.

Now I have got Pixel 5 with Android 11. The Google Phone app actually supports call recording but apparently not in my country (New Zealand — even though recording without consent is perfectly legal here so long as you are a party to the call): there is no "Call recording" menu option in the settings.

After some research I have found:

- About a dozen apps in Play Store offering call recording functionality; and
- That in later versions of Android, Google has taken measures to make call recording more difficult. Installing/configuring the apps to make call recording actually work is now complicated.

That makes the [2014 question/answers](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3348/call-recording-app-for-android) slightly outdated now.

So, before I go through the trouble of installing the available apps one by one to find one that works smoothly, I am wondering if anyone has done it already. Is there a particular call recording app you would recommend for Android 11?

Comment: Great question.  Upvoted.  I'm looking forward to reading the answers.